# How to manage Android MVVM, Android Architecture component (LiveData) with DataBinding for many UI fields?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata

I know Android MVVM, LiveData and DataBinding. But, I have a scenario in which I have many input UI fields such as Email, Password, Confirm Password and etc. I can map those fields with ViewModel.

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
        public MutableLiveData<String> email = new MutableLiveData<>();
        public MutableLiveData<String> password = new MutableLiveData<>();
        .
        .
        .
}
```

I bound this LoginViewModel with the following XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="viewModel.LoginViewModel" />

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:context=".view.MainActivity">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="@={loginViewModel.email}" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="@={loginViewModel.password}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Actually, I have more UI fields so which ideal approach should I follow? Whether to declare the exact same LiveData in ViewModel based on my UI. Like 10 UI fields should have 10 LiveData in ViewModel.

Comment: follow this link these helps for me https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/android-architecture-components-databinding-dependent-properties-6e8eba6c8b13

Comment: @AravindV Thanks for this reference. Actually, I know LiveData and Databinding. Your link doesn't convey my question's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model should expose 10 data fields if your UI can show it (don't overload UI). It's how MVVM works. But! You should expose differed types of fields depends on field behaviour:

- `LiveData` for read-only fields (e.g. `TextView`)
- `MutableLiveData` for mutable fields, two way databinding (e.g. `EditText`)
- non `LiveData` type for constant (read-only) data. If you know data not changed during view model life cycle, you can expose data without `LiveData`. In this case your data will be binded once when you setup view model variable.